# Restoring Oracle prod backup to test server with new database name

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, windows, restore

I need to restore an Oracle production database (aaprod) to a test server that already is home to a test database (aatest) under a new name (bbtest).  I have a cold backup of the production database

Questions:  What is the appropriate approach to restoring this production database to a test server under a new database name using the cold backup?

Easy to do with SQL Server, Oracle is a new gig.

Comment: is the underlying OS windows or Unix?

Comment: My bad, it is Windows.

Comment: How was the database backed up? Did you use RMAN or just manually copy the data files, control files, init.ora etc?

Comment: No RMAN is involved so far.  This is a manual process for the data, control, etc.

Comment: Do the data files for the aatest instance have identical paths as aaprod? (A different approach is needed if this is the case, as bbtest will need its data files renaming)

Comment: Yes, the respective paths for aatest and aaprod are identical.

Answer (score 1):

rule #1) use rman for backup, recovery and cloning of databases.

since this was a user managed backup, and you need your datafiles on a different location, there are a few things to do.

1. 1) copy the file to where you want
2. 2) create a pfile.ora that references your control_files
3. 3) startup mount your database

at this moment you have control_files that still refer to the original datafiles locations. They need to be redirected.

1. 4) for all your files in v$datafile, issue "alter database rename
   file '/old/name' to '/new/name';
2. 5) for all your members in v$logfile, issue "alter database rename
   file '/old/name' to '/new/name';

now you should be able to open your database.

1. 6) alter database open;

If you get problems before or during mount, it is probably because of wrong dbname, db_unique_name. Set them as they were/are in prod.